# jquery ajax call not able to see response data

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ajax response I am getting is always empty!
Interestingly, if I copy paste that URL in browser, I do get a proper html snippet (test ad) back. I guess this is related to some cross-site call stuff. Need some help/pointers as response is not json. Its html code.

Please look at the code - http://pastie.org/1120352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are fetching data from some different host.

You need to have a look at [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy):

> In computing, the same origin policy
>   is an important security concept for a
>   number of browser-side programming
>   languages, such as JavaScript. The
>   policy permits scripts running on
>   pages originating from the same site
>   to access each other's methods and
>   properties with no specific
>   restrictions, but prevents access to
>   most methods and properties across
>   pages on different sites.

For you to be able to get data, it has to be:

**Same protocol and host**

You need to implement [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-) to workaround it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is most likely cross-domain restrictions.

Can you state whether the web page itself is on the same domain and subdomain as the URL you are requesting (`http://ads.admarvel.com/`)?

If you are not on the same domain then you will need to make a request to a proxy script to grab the data.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it seems like your code has an extra closing bracket and parentesis.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$.get(url,{}, function (d) {
        alert(d);
}
```

});

***});***

Comment: Oops! ... typo. Its the extra curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

Also, try adding type attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
  $.get(
     url: url,
     data: {}, 
     callback: function (d) {
        alert(d);
     },
     type: 'json' \\ or whatever the call is returning
  ); 
});
```